# 1-Wasserstein distance between two multivariate normal

Tags: reference-request, pr.probability, probability-distributions, optimal-transportation, wasserstein-distance

The $p$-Wasserstein between two measures $\nu_1$ and $\nu_2$ on $X$ is given by

$$d_p(\nu_{1},\nu_{2})=\left(\underset{\pi\in\Gamma(\nu_{1},\nu_{2})}{\inf}\int_{\mathbf{\mathcal{X}}^{2}}d(x,y)^p\pi(dx,dy)\right)^{\frac 1p}$$

where $\Gamma(\nu_{1},\nu_{2})$ is the set of all couplings between $\nu_1$ and $\nu_2$. For $X=\mathbb{R}^d$ and $d$ being the euclidean distance the optimal transport between $\nu_{1}=N(m,V)$ and $\nu_{2}=N(n,U)$ is well known for $p=2$ see e.g. [On Wasserstein geometry of the space of Gaussian measures by Asuka Takatsu](https://arxiv.org/abs/0801.2250). However what is known for $p=1$ for the Euclidean distance or other "reasonable" metrics? I am interested in explicit formulas or sharp bounds.

Comment: Interested in this question as well...

Comment: Are you interested in explicit formulas for normal distributions only, or for other specific measures as well?

Comment: Can't one use the fact that the optimal map between Gaussians is known explicitly? and this map does not depend on the exponent $p>1$

Answer (score 5):

For $p=1$ one can bound the 1-Wasserstein metric by
$$|m-n| + \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^{d} \left[ 
\left(
\sqrt{\lambda_i} - \sqrt{\gamma_i}\right)^2 + 2\sqrt{\lambda_i\gamma_i}(1-v_i\cdot u_i)
\right]}$$

when $\lambda_i$ and $\gamma_i$ are the $i^{th}$ eigen values of $U$ and $V$ respectively, $v_1,\ldots,v_d$ and $u_1,\ldots,u_d$  are the corresponding orthonormal basis of eigen-vectors.

See [Chafai & Malrieu](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0805.0987.pdf) Lemma 2.4.

Although this bound seems close-in nature to the $p=2$ bound, I'm not sure if it is sharp.

Comment: There is a typo in your bound. The "$uv$" term should be $(1-v_i\cdot u_i)$. Also, note that this bound is an equality when the covariance matrices are equal (infact in this case all $W_p(\nu_1,\nu_2) = \|m-n\|_2$ for all $p \ge 1$).

Comment: Fixed. Thanks for pointing it out